# Dense Subsets: If $f|_D = g|_D$ then $f=g$ (proof)

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, metric-spaces

> Let $f,g : (X, \rho) \longrightarrow (Y,d)$ be continuous functions
>   and $D$ a **dense** subset of $X$. Show that, if $f|_D = g|_D$ then
>   $f=g$, where $\cdot |_D$ is the restriction to $D$.

Let $w = f - g$. Then, we have
$$
w(z) \equiv 0, \, \forall z \in D
$$

Also, the fact that $D$ is a dense subset of $X$ implies that
$$
\exists y \in D, \, \forall x\in X, \, \forall \delta >0:  \rho(x,y) < \delta
$$
and because $w$ is a continuous function, we have
$$
d(w(x),w(y)) < \varepsilon \iff w(x) \longrightarrow w(y) \equiv 0
$$
Is this sufficient to show that $w$ is identically equal to zero?

Comment: Note, in a general metric space we don't have subtraction, so $w$ as above is not well defined, nevertheless you can take $d(f(x)-g(x))$.

Comment: @Berci You mean $d(f(x),g(x))$ ?

Comment: Try to prove that $x \mapsto d(f(x),g(x)) \in \mathbb{R}$ is continous. Then for each $x \in D^c$, find a sequence $\{x_n\}$ converge to $x$ and use continuity to show that $f(x)=g(x)$.